# Qthread is catching up after "pause"

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyside2

I've made an application with pyside2 (qml).

The purpose is to read and present the values comming from an arduino to a chart.

The data is send every second over the serial connection to the pc.

To achieve this I had to create an QThread for not freezing up the UI.
[Used explenation here.](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/)

In the UI I've a button to start/pause the app.

The application is almost working as expected:
Only when I pause the app and say after a minute or so I resume the app (QThread) I got a lot of data gathered from the Arduino when this should not be happening.

I expect as long as the thread is "pausing" it won't read data that I don't need.

How do I fix it so it won't read the data when the thread in on "pause" ?

**main.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, Slot, QObject, QThread
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

class Worker(QThread):
    data = Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, ctrl):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.ctrl = ctrl

    def run(self):
        while True:
            while self.ctrl["running"]:
                self.data.emit(arduino.read_arduino())
            else:
                time.sleep(0)

            if self.ctrl["break"]:
                break

class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.ctrl = {"break": False, "running": True}
        self.worker = Worker(self.ctrl)

    @Slot()
    def start_measurement(self):       
         if not self.thread.isRunning():
             self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
             self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
             self.worker.data.connect(self.handle_arduino_raw_data)
             self.thread.start()
         else:
              self.ctrl["running"] = True   
         if self.ctrl["running"] = True:
              self.ctrl["running"] = False

    @Slot(str)
    def handle_arduino_raw_data(self, data):    
     # handle the data received from the arduino
```

**arduino.py**

```
def read_arduino(self):
         raw_data = self.ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
         return raw_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the data all the time, but only emit it when you're `running`, otherwise throw it away?

```
    def run(self):
        while not self.ctrl["break"]:
            data = arduino.read_arduino()
            if self.ctrl["running"]:
                self.data.emit(data)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: your snippet was not completly what I was looking for, but I got the right direction. I made the following adjustment: ´´´ def run(self):
        while True:
            raw_data = arduino.read_arduino()
            if self.ctrl["running"]:
                self.data.emit(raw_data)
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

            if self.ctrl["break"]:
                break´´´

Comment: Glad I could help. Your snippet seems practically equivalent aside from the sleep duration.